# Foundation with SASS, compiled with gulp only importing one component

Tags: css, sass, gulp, zurb-foundation

Here is my current (the relevant portion) gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/stylesheets/main.scss')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(gulpif(production, cssmin()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});
```

With following main.scss:

```
@import "normalize";
@import "foundation";
```

here's the folder structure of the app/stylesheets folder:

```
-- app -- stylesheets ---foundation.scss
                       |-normalize.scss
                       |-main.scss
                       |-foundation-------_functions.scss
                                        |-_settings.scss
                                        |-_components/
```

The resulting main.css file after gulp processing ends up containing only the normalize.scss styles and what looks like the _tables.scss and _visibility.scss components.

I have tried using includePaths with gulp-sass and that didn't compile anything at all.

Also, importing the css rather than scss in the main.scss file works just fine, but I want to change the row-width setting to 100%, so I'd like to use the scss files.

All foundation files were left as is. Please help me understand why not all the components are importing! Thank you!

Comment: try @import "settings" before foundation, or read this http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html

Answer (score 1):

Check the foundation.scss file, you need to initialize the mixins to be available, either by calling them one by one or calling them all with the provided fun by foundation:

```
@import 'foundation';
@include foundation-everything;
```

Hope this helps.